# Is it possible to modify the docker container produced when committing chaincode in the test-network of Hyperledger fabric?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, commit, chaincode

I'm using the hyper-ledger fabric test-network. I created a simple Chaincode that performs, among other tasks, json validation, which simply means that this function takes 2 Json files as parameters and says whether or not these Json files are alike, so to speak. Details on that not important.

I am able to install and commit this chaincode with no problem and I can see that this chaincode with this JsonValidation function works, but with only one caveat: I need to manually create these 2 Json files I mentioned earlier in the docker containers that are created when committing the chaincode. Those containers are created when successfully excecuting the next command line:

`$ peer lifecycle chaincode commit -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --channelID mychannel --name basic --version 1.0 --sequence 1 ...(command line truncated)`

I was wondering if you know a way of binding or mounting this files before (or after?) the creation of these containers. I don't know if there is some trick in the previous command line that facilitates that. I know the concept of Private Data Collections, which might be implemented down the road in this project I am working on, but I just need a 'quick' practical solution for this, if such a thing exists.

Thank you, fellas.

Answer (score 0):

A few options that might work for you:

1. The chaincode to be installed is packaged within a `code.tar.gz` file. If your JSON files are not going to change then perhaps you could package them within your chaincode source and then load them from the source location at runtime. See the [chaincode lifecycle documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode_lifecycle.html#step-one-packaging-the-smart-contract) for some information on the packaged structure.
2. Instead of using the default (Docker in Docker) chaincode builder, you could deploy your chaincode as an external service. This requires you to manage the running of the chaincode but you then have complete flexibility to control the chaincode content, and how and where it runs. The [chaincode-external](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-external) sample demonstrates this approach. This is also the approach used for rapid development and debugging of chaincode in the Smart Contract Development section of a [workshop](https://github.com/hyperledgendary/full-stack-asset-transfer-guide) used at the 2022 Hyperledger Global Forum.
3. If you are deploying to Kubernetes then the [fabric-builder-k8s](https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/fabric-builder-k8s) external chaincode builder allows you to build your own chaincode Docker images up-front and then have them used by the chaincode deployment process.

Comment: Great places to start! I had no idea about chaincode as external service, which makes sense of course. People should be able to customize these things.

Thank you!